# The browser doesn't send token cookie on ssr request when deployed my nextjs app on vercel

Tags: cookies, server-side-rendering, vercel, next.js13

I'm encountering an issue with cookies not being sent in server-side rendered (SSR) requests on my Next.js app when it's deployed to Vercel, but it works perfectly fine on localhost during development. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
import { parseCookies } from "nookies";

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    try {
      const { req } = context;
      
      const cookies = parseCookies({ req });
      
  
      const token = cookies["connect.sid"];
  console.log('token', token)
  
  
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/front/api/v1/profile`,
        {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            Cookie: `connect.sid=${token}`,
          },
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );

      console.log('url in sign in', `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/front/api/v1/profile`)
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch user profile");
      }
  
      const useResponse = await response.json();
      const user = useResponse.data;
  
      let destination = "/";
      if (user.Role.name === "Parent") {
        destination = "/parent/dashboard";
      } else if (user.Role.name === "Teacher") {
        destination = "/teacher/dashboard";
      }
  
      return {
        props: {
          user,
        },
        redirect: {
          destination,
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return {
        props: {},
      };
    }
  };
```

The issue is that when I deploy my app to Vercel, the token cookie appears to be undefined in SSR requests, as indicated by the console.log('token', token) statement. However, when I run the app locally, the token cookie is correctly retrieved.

I've ensured that my cookie settings and domain settings are correct, and I've checked my environment variables. What could be causing this discrepancy between my localhost and production deployment on Vercel?

Is there anything specific to Vercel or Next.js deployment that could be affecting the handling of cookies in SSR?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.